Space character in Webview's Source causes net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error
In a .NET 8 Maui project that targets Android API 34, I'm using a Webview with a Source defined by a variable: myWebView.Source = "https://example.com/?q=" + myVariable
If there is one or more leading or random spaces (%20) in myVariable, then I get a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND:

Webpage not available
The webpage at
file:///android_asset/https://example.com/?q=%20%20Test
could not be loaded because:
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

If there are only trailing spaces, there is no problem and the site loads fine. Of course the same is true if there are no spaces at all.
Is there a workaround?

If there are only trailing spaces, there is no problem and the site loads fine. Of course the same is true if there are no spaces at all....Is there a workaround?: Is this a trick question? The workaround seems obvious - don't use spaces.

The following may be of interest: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback

@user246821 The query string often consists of 2 or more words separated by spaces, so unfortunately it is an actual and common problem. The URL opens without issues in Xamarin.Forms Webview and in every web browser, so definitely that's a MAUI related bug. I wonder if there is a way to avoid it or if the only way is to wait for a bug fix.

Have you submitted a bug report? If not, then you may be waiting a very long time.

I'm going to submit one very soon, but I'm not so sure that I won't have to wait even if I do it.

If the space causes exception, then why not avoid it. You may try replacing the space, myvariable.Replace(" ","%20").

@LiqunShen-MSFT
I tried the replace method with no success. That was to be expected though, because as you can see in the error I get, the space has already been automatically replaced with %20.

Does it happen  if you hard coded the Webview source?

No it doesn't. I have submitted a bug report: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/23767#issuecomment-2244838747 mentioning that detail.

Thanks for your feedback. You may follow up the issue and get the latest updates. Btw, have you tried using handler to invoke native android webview?

@LiqunShen-MSFT
No, I haven't tried the handler. If the bug isn't going to be fixed soon, I may give it a try and hopefully, if the issue isn't related with the Android WebView, I may use it as a temporary solution.

Okay, you may keep following up this issue. And if we want to try Handler, you may refer to Handlers
